# Deep vs "shallow" calibration of option pricing models

Tags: option-pricing, machine-learning, calibration, neural-networks

I am currently investigating the application of deep learning in calibrating option pricing models, specifically, models of rough volatility, such as rBergomi. While there is a lot of research on using deep neural nets as fast option pricing engines with market and model parameters as input features, there seems to be practically nothing on using gradient boosting to approximate the pricing function in some option pricing model. Given that gradient boosting usually outperforms deep learning on tabular data, why is the research concentrated on deep calibration?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between

1. "fast pricing" that is mimicking the function that maps characteristics of the observables (what you call market data and parameters in your question) to the value of a derivative contract that has been already computed (but a way that is slow)
2. "deep pricing" that is computing the value and the optimal hedging strategy of a contingent claim.

The fact that the second one is called "deep" is compatible with your question: deep neural networks are used that for, whereas for the first one (learning a mapping) a lot of other options are used.

For fast pricing boosting methods are used too. See for instance

- Davis, Jesse, Laurens Devos, Sofie Reyners, and Wim Schoutens. "[Gradient boosting for quantitative finance](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/p.j.c.spreij/winterschool/19ReynersPaper.pdf)" Journal of Computational Finance 24, no. 4 (2020)
- Ferraz, João Diogo Marques, Master Thesis "[Pricing options using the XGBoost Model](https://www.repository.utl.pt/bitstream/10400.5/27264/1/DM-JDMF-2022.pdf)" , Instituto Superior de Economia e Gestão, 2022.

**Fast pricing** is about using a database of slow numerical simulation over a set $\Omega$ of examples of mappings $X\in \Omega\mapsto Y=\mathbb{E}(\mbox{payoff})$.

The advantage is that if you have made simulations for two examples $X_1$ and $X_2$ and you face in real-time a new configuration $X_{new}$ that is not "*too different*"from them, the ML also will **interpollate** and give quickly a result.

**Deep pricing** is different: you want to solve the HJB characterising the claim; it is made of two component: the *value* of the claim (that is what you will interpolate later with *fast pricing*) and **the optimal control** that is the hedging portfolio that replicates the exposure of the claim.

This is commonly called the [Howard (or policy-value iteration) method](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10589-021-00278-3). When you use machine learning you have to use two algorithms:

- one to emulate the optimal control, solving the optimum part of the HJB
- and once the control is set, the HJB boils down to a PDE for a value function, that you need to emulate using another neural net.

Globally, when you use this process you have to get 2 neural nets to converge simultaneously. And in a sense it is like a larger "global neural net", it works decently well. People who tried other algos (like boosting) did not obtained (at my knowledge) good result because you have to control simultaneously the convergence of the two algos. For neural nets it is not that difficult (you can synchronize their learning rates). It somehow looks like Q-learning of Reinforcement Learning.

A way to understand this effect is to look at what happens when you introduce another convergence: when you want to solve a **Mean Field Game** of stochastic controlers. Imagine you want your hedging process to take into account the fact that **other banks are hedging similar products** and that all the hedging trades create a coupling via [market impact](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.4342).
Recently Angiuli, Andrea, Jean-Pierre Fouque, and Mathieu Laurière. "[Unified reinforcement Q-learning for mean field game and control problems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.13912.pdf)" Mathematics of Control, Signals, and Systems 34, no. 2 (2022): 217-271.
If you are interested in this kind of question I recommend Capponi, Agostino, and C.-A. L, eds. [Machine Learning and Data Sciences for Financial Markets: A Guide to Contemporary Practices](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/machine-learning-and-data-sciences-for-financial-markets/8BB31611662A96D0AB93A8A26E2D0D0A). Cambridge University Press, 2023. There is a full part: [New Frontiers for Stochastic Control in Finance](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/machine-learning-and-data-sciences-for-financial-markets/new-frontiers-for-stochastic-control-in-finance/F9438F331D35842163993B6CB2B06417) with 6 chapters on it.

Comment: Wow, nice answer!